# Adding new tag in table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

All I want to do is to add after last `<td>` some `<span>` tag with some text.
Any suggestions? This example doesn't work:

Example looks like this:

```js
 function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerHTML;
   x.innerHTML = "<span>hey</span>"
 }

 window.onload = function() {
   myFunction();
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="first">
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerHTML` will return string. Returned value does not have method `innerHTML`

variable `x` holds string in the example. You are calling `x.innerHTML` of returned string which does not exist.

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
  x.innerHTML = "<span>hey</span>";
}
window.onload = myFunction;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="first">
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to append `span` element after existing text then use this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerHTML += "<span>hey</span>";
}
window.onload = myFunction;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="first">
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {   var x=document.getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
                      
x.innerHTML="<span>hey</span>"}
window.onload = function() {
myFunction();
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="first">
<td>one</td>
<td>two</td>
<td>three</td>
</tr>
</table>
```